# Недоумение с ID пользователя(facebook)

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-api, request, facebook-graph-api

Есть бот, вот ответ от вебхука при запросе

```
{'message': {'mid': 'mid.$cAAaT_vHxxjJocGnMFFiPySDHGIAS',
         'seq': 913,
         'text': 'qqqq'},
         'recipient': {'id': '1909878095893246'},
         'sender': {'id': '1563536027048506'},
         'timestamp': 1521477780500}
```

Пытаюсь перейти на страничку пользователя, ID которого находится в `[sender][id]`

`https://www.facebook.com/1563536027048506` 
Получаю ошибку

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хорошо, пытаюсь вручную кликнуть на страничку, дабы увидеть какая ссылка сформируется в адресной строке и подстраиваю запрос под нее

`https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100024764175564` как видно, id отличается от того, который присылает вебхук

Пытаюсь поменять запрос на `https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=1563536027048506`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос. Как мне получить хоть какую-то информацию, чтоб с помощью нее можно было сформировать запрос в адресной строке для перехода на страничку пользователя?

На всякий случай прикреплю код

```
class FbBotView(generic.View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.request.GET['hub.verify_token'] == VERIFY_TOKEN:
            return HttpResponse(self.request.GET['hub.challenge'])
        else:
            return HttpResponse('Error, invalid token')

    @method_decorator(csrf_exempt)
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return generic.View.dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        incoming_message = json.loads(self.request.body.decode('utf-8'))
        for entry in incoming_message['entry']:
            for message in entry['messaging']:
                if 'message' in message:
                    pprint(message)    
        return HttpResponse()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В документации у facebook посмотрим что в payload у вебхука:

```
{
  "sender":{
    "id":"<PSID>"
  },
  "recipient":{
    "id":"<USER_ID>"
  }...
```

Как мы видим в sender стоит не `USER_ID`, а `PSID` - Page Scoped User ID. Это означает, что пользователь в различных приложениях будет иметь совершенно разный ID, который вы сможете видеть и никак не будет иметь отношения к его реальному ID. API, по которому вы можете понять что это один и тот же человек в ваших приложениях (сравнение PSID между приложениями) описан [тут](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/connecting-accounts/?locale=ru_RU).

Еще одна хитрость для связывания пользователя через Graph API описана на [chatbotsmagazine.com](https://chatbotsmagazine.com/fb-messenger-bot-how-to-identify-a-user-via-page-app-scoped-user-ids-f95b807b7e46)

Получить реальный (global) пользовательский ID в вашем случае невозможно.